# What is the practical difference between swept collisions and the other?

Tags: ios, box2d, physics, game-physics, chipmunk

I'm actually investigating differences between Box2D and Chipmunk.

They say Box2D has a killer "swept collision" feature:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/current-state-of-box2d-vs-chipmunk-debate/#post-344685

Which sound cool, only problem is that I have no idea what is that. :D
Can somebody shed me a light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody at Box2D forum just answered before:
http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=39095#p39095

Comment: Note that the testbed contains tests that showcase the CCD functionality. plus the "cannon" you can fire with the spacebar in all demos also demos it well.